# not able to save turtle graphics image

Tags: python, excel, vba, turtle-graphics

I am using excel VBA to call the python file to draw a turtle graphics and save it in a .ps file but is not saving the file. when I directly execute from command prompt then it does save the file.
Can someone please help!

**Here is the VBA commands**

```
Sub RunPythonScript()
'Declare our variablesstrong text
Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
Dim a, b, c, k, t As Integer
'Creae as a new shell Object
Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
a = Range("e3").Value
b = Range("f3").Value
c = Range("g3").Value
k = Range("h3").Value
'Provide the file path to the Python Exe
PythonExe = """C:\Windows\py.exe"""
PythonScript = "D:\comsol\code0.5.py"
objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript & " " & a & " " & b & " " & c & " " & k
End Sub
```

**And here is the python code**

```
import os
import sys

t=turtle.Turtle()

a=int(sys.argv[1])
b=int(sys.argv[2])
c=int(sys.argv[3])
k=int(sys.argv[4])

for i in range(k):
    t.color("Black","Black")
    t.begin_fill()
    t.forward(a)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(b)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(a)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(b)
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(c+a)
    t.pendown()
    t.color("Yellow","Yellow")
    t.begin_fill()
    t.forward(a)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(b)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(a)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(b)
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(c+a)
    t.pendown()

command=turtle.getscreen().getcanvas().postscript(file='canva1.ps')
os.system(command)
turtle.done()
```

Comment: What happens when you change `PythonExe & PythonScript` to `PythonExe & " " & PythonScript`

Comment: Yes I tried, it's not working

Comment: Check the values of a,b,c and k if they are ok? Try and get the string from `PythonExe & PythonScript & " " & a & " " & b & " " & c & " " & k` and then see what do you get. also use that to run it from command line. does it work?

Comment: yes, it's printing the right data on the command line. the only issue is that it's not saving the postscript file when executed from VBA

Comment: before `objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript & " " & a & " " & b & " " & c & " " & k` , can you type `Debug.Print PythonExe & " " & PythonScript & " " & a & " " & b & " " & c & " " & k` and share what do you get?

Comment: no, that didnt worked!

Comment: What do you mean? Please read my above message again

Comment: Yes I did exactly what you said in the above message but I did not get any different results or message

Comment: Debug.print will shown the result in immediate window